# Порядок строк. Объединение. sql.

Tags: select, sql

Здравствуйте.

У меня возник вопрос, по поводу того, как именно работает объединение (JOIN) в sql. В частности, в каком порядке идут строки.

Т.е., к примеру имеются 2 таблицы A и B:

```
A:    B:
1 1   1 5
2 3   2 8
```

Связь будет по 1-ому полю.

SELECT A.number, B.number FROM A JOIN B ON A.number = B.number

Как будут идти строки (имеется ввиду не в результирующем наборе, а в процессе обработки)? Так или нет:

```
1 1
1 2
2 1
2 2
```

Где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: Ну в результате две, а в каком порядке просматриваются отбрасываемые варианты, это вряд ли где-то зафиксировано. Выбрасываются, и ладно.

Comment: "(имеется ввиду не в результирующем наборе, а в процессе обработки)"

Comment: Да я уже комментарий исправил. Могу дать точный ответ: не знаю. В свою очередь, мне стало интересно, нафига это знать?

Comment: Стало интересно, как это работает.
Кстати, возможно можно будет глянуть в исходниках какой-нибудь opensource СУБД. Хотя скорее всего это будет частный случай, так как в разных СУБД обработка может быть и скорее всего будет, реализована по разному.

Comment: Должно быть по-разному даже для одной СУБД при разном соотношении количества значение в первом/втором, наличием/отсутствием индексов по этим полям и т.д.
В MS SQL был вроде анализатор, который помогал планировать запросы, в числе прочего составляя план запроса.

Comment: Я просто хочу понять, алгоритм сравнивает одну строку с каждой строкой из другой таблицы сразу или это происходит как-то вразнобой.

А если проверяет сразу, то алгоритм, по-моему мнению, будет единым для всех случаев, не считая каких-то особых исключений.

Comment: Единым алгоритм может быть в том случае, когда СУБД -- студенческая курсовая.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

скорее за все порядок выдачи результата будет зависить от того в каком порядке данные физически лежат на диске. с другой стороны, некоторые данные могут уже быть закешированы, это тоже может повлиять на результаты выборки. если обобщить: порядок следования будет случайным

если вам нужен определенный порядок следования записей в результате, то лучше явно задать сортировку. это еще один шаг к написанию хорошего ПО с прогнозированным поведением

Answer (score 2):

Это называется СОЕДИНЕНИЕМ. Объединение - это UNION.
Существует несколько алгоритмов выполнения соединения, из которых выбирает оптимизатор. Например,

```
nested loops
hash join
merge join
```

Порядок обработки зависит от выбранного алгоритма.
Описание каждого алгоритма вы можете найти в документации к используемой СУБД.